# what's the proper name for the UI widget used on mobiles for message histories

Tags: mobile

Opening SMS or whatsapp or any other short message system on a mobile usually opens a scrollable, chronological history of messages, with my own messages appearing in right aligned boxes and the messages of the other person in left aligned boxes.

Is there any official name for this kind of widget?

Comment: "Chat history" inside a "scroll pane".  Not everything has to have a fancy name unto itself. :)

Comment: Programmatically, in iOS it would be *infinite-scroll custom tableview*. But for users, I would simply call it *chat history*, or the *chat screen*.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "official name" for it. Naming it would depend on the platform. In iOS call them "Views" (I forgot which exactly), while in HTML, they're just elements (think `<li>` in a scrollable, fixed-dimension `<ul>`).

Something like "list" in a "scrollable" would be the simplest way to call it.

The design itself is called a "threaded view" or "conversation view", where the current item is placed along with the other items of the same topic. Similar to a forum thread, where replies to a certain topic is posted in one collection, SMS apps post conversations into one collection per contact.